# Whats eating my memory?

Tags: server, debian

I often face the problem that something is eating away on my memory, but I can't put my finger on what it is.

I have redis, mysql, ruby, php and apache running on the same server, it's been running fine, but all of a sudden something is consuming too much memory. The TOP command doesn't tell me anything that worries me.

How can I find the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `htop` in a screen session, press F6, order by MEM, and you'll see that. Alternatively you can set up a `munin-node`, and get a graph that visualizes your system-behavior. `atop -m` also works very well for me. Some systems hide super-use processes. In that case perform your analysis as root.