# How can I get my system performance back again?

Tags: performance

I have had this laptop for about 3 months running Ubuntu and it is now considerably slow performing every function than when I first installed Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried running a virus scanner. I have turned on "preload". I am running "zram". Even tried "bleachbit" but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Do any of these help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/15876/whats-eating-my-memory or [http://askubuntu.com/questions/36141/frequent-cpu-hogging][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36141/frequent-cpu-hogging

Answer (score 1):

System performance, as I'm sure you are aware is a very complicated subject.

However, I think that it would be fair to say that at a basic level it's the result of three things;

1. CPU Utilization
2. Memory Utilization
3. Disk Utilization

Use, the information below **only** as a guide to what **May** be slowing things down.

Ubuntu has a package called `top` for monitoring system processes and their CPU and Memory % utilization [More information on the top command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/top.1.html).

Using `top` you should be able to identify any processor, or memory hogging tasks.

1. Open a terminal prompt,
2. type `$ top`,
3. Look at the top processes and their CPU and Memory utilization

Obviously, the list should not add up to 100% of CPU or Memory ;o).

If it does (or close >80%) you may look to increase the resources or reduce the load.

To reduce the load;

4. Locate the processes that you do not need and make a note of its name,
5. Exit `$ top` using `(Ctrl-C)`,
6. Get the process details, type `$ sudo ps -ef | grep my-unwanted-process-name`,
7. Stop the unwanted process, type `$ sudo pkill my-unwanted-process-name`,

Lastly, you may want to also [Check Ubuntu 12.04 system requirements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125280/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-12-04-lts).

I hope that this helps to start you in the right direction.

Comment: you can also use `htop`, gives you a nice overview of what's running and you can configure how it is displayed.

Comment: Deleting 100 and more gigabytes helped me ;)